# Reference sought for back chaining algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, logic-programming

I am looking for a precise description of the algorithm for inference by back chaining. Whenever I search, I just find the standard example lifted from Russell and Norvig with no formal description of the algorithm.

Comment: What's wrong with the Wikipedia article?